# Use a type to declare a method

Tags: typescript, type-alias

I know how to use a type to declare a class function

```
type myType = (val: number) => void;

class myClass {
    myFunction1 = function (val) {  }
    myFunction1Typed : myType  = function (val) {  }
}
```

However, I don't know how to do the same with a method notation

```
type myType = (val: number) => void;

class myClass {
    myMethod (val) {  }
    myMethodTyped : myType (val) {  }   // not valid  !!!!!!
}
```

I haven't been able to find anything about this in the documentation

My problem is that I have a great codebase of clases declared as methods (the second example that I posted).

Now, we are beginning to introduce types for some of the functions, gradually.

We can of course change the declaration of the functions as we go, but it would be easier if we could stick with our current style and just add the type somehow.

Comment: A class function is a method.

Comment: @Kornflexx I know that. However, the syntax is different. I just want to know how to do the same using the method syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that your second syntax attempt is simply not valid/supported in TypeScript. That might also be the reason why you cannot find anything in the documentation about it.

Note that TypeScript is basically just JavaScript with additional support for strong typing. Except for a few exceptions (in which case the TypeScript compiler handles compiling/transpiling certain fancy TypeScript expressions to legal targeted JavaScript expressions), everything you write in TypeScript should basically still be legal JavaScript if you strip out all TypeScript specific stuff.

TypeScript can deduce and infer a lot, but not everything. Your explicit `myType` type can only be used to make sure that you do not make any datatype-related mistakes when implementing your `myMethodTyped` method accordingly in your `myClass` class.

Also note that TypeScript provides the concept of *interfaces* in addition to types to make sure that your functions, methods, classes, etc. are strongly type-checked. But I am not sure if using an interface would be a better choice in your case. Both types and interfaces have their own strengths and weaknesses, so it's up to you to decide which feature to use.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was not trying to avoid the val in the example, I was just trying to show a little of my intent. I have edited my question to make it more clear. Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there is no way to do this. The closest you can get is to use an interface:

```js
interface IMyClass {
  myMethod(val: any): number;
}

class MyClass implements IMyClass {
  myMethod(val: any) {
    return 5;
  }
}
```

So by this I mean that these two interface are slightly different:

```js
interface IMyClass {
  myMethod(val: any): number;
}

interface IMyClass2 {
  myMethod: (val: any) => number;
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question to make it clearer. What I am trying to get is a way to make those changes minimal, so your solution is not what I am looking for. Thanks any way.